# How to make osgEarth automatically manage HGT elevation tiles?

Tags: c++, elevation, osgearth, hgt

I'm trying to add an elevation layer to my program that's based on osgEarth. I've seen an example, `osgearth_city`, available in osgEarth source tree, which loads a `TMSElevationLayer` like this:

```
TMSElevationLayer* layer = new TMSElevationLayer();
layer->setURL("http://readymap.org/readymap/tiles/1.0.0/116/");
map->addLayer(layer);
```

But what I need is to use a set of local `*.hgt` tiles in the directory layout like `/path/to/hgt/N/37/N55E037.hgt` for the 55°N 37°E tile. I've found that `GDALElevationLayer` can be used to load individual `*.hgt` files, with

```
const auto gdal=new GDALElevationLayer;
gdal->setURL("/home/ruslan/hgt/N/37/N55E037.hgt");
map->addLayer(gdal);
```

But this way I'd have to manage the tileset myself: watch the location of the camera, load the required tiles, unload the ones no longer needed etc..

How can I instruct osgEarth to do the tile management automatically, like it does with `TMSElevationLayer`, but using the local `*.hgt` files?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you create a VRT file using GDAL's **gdalbuildvrt** command line tool, [as described here](http://docs.osgearth.org/en/latest/data.html#loading-a-directory-of-files).

Also, since you are using DTED data, be sure to tell osgEarth to use the correct EGM96 reference ellipsoid:

```
layer->setVerticalDatum("egm96");
```

Comment: Is EGM96 always the correct ellipsoid for elevation data? Or do I have to somehow check that my dataset uses it?

Comment: DTED is known to be expressed relative to the EGM96 geoid. Not all elevation is, but it's pretty common. Unfortunately datasets do not usually convey that information so you have to figure it out and tell osgearth yourself.

Comment: For some reason, when I set `GDALElevationLayer::setURL` to my `.vrt` file, most of the tiles take forever to load (after several have loaded) — even the map tiles, which work fine without this layer or when I pass the single `.hgt` file directly to it. Can the tile manager of `GDALElevationLayer` somehow conflict with that of `XYZImageLayer`?